# probability distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, probability

Just wanted to know if the value we get by passing, say, `random.normal(shape=(3,2))` in the Tensorflow, etc, are normally distributed or if they are randomly chosen from a set of values that are normally distributed? If it's the latter one, then they could be unintentionally belonging to a uniform or any other distribution with some different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow's [random.normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal) "outputs random values from a normal distribution".

Values from other distributions are sampled by their respective functions: [tf.random.uniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform), [tf.random.gamm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/gamma), [tf.random.poisson](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/poisson).

Comment: But those "random" values could make a non-random set of values for some other distribution. Like you can plot them out.